# Python : Get all occurences from list with startswith, endswith and lenght

Tags: python

I would like to make a search with some conditions into my list of words.

This is part of my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open(r"C:\Users\Valentin\Desktop\list.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

all_words = ','.join(content)
end = all_words.endswith('e')
```

My list looks like this :

> 'cresson', 'crête', 'Créteil', 'crétin', 'creuse', 'creusé',
>   'creuser',...

I would like to set these conditions :

- Start with letter 'C'
- End with letter 'E'
- Length : 9 characters

How I can do that ?

Comment: Case sensitive or insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming case insensitivity, and that you have access to f-strings (Python 3.6):

```
[s for s in content if len(s) == 9 and f'{s[0]}{s[-1]}'.lower() == 'ce']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do in one list-comprehension:

```
content = ['cresson', 'crête', 'Créteil', 'crétin', 'creuse', 'creusé', 'creuser']

result = [x for x in content if len(x) == 9 and x.startswith() == 'c' and x.endswith() == 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open(r"C:\Users\Valentin\Desktop\list.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
#print(content) 

result = [i for i in content if i.startswith('c')]
result2 = [i for i in result if i.endswith('e')]
result3 = [i for i in result2 if len(i)==9]
print(result3)
```